# $n$th root of power series when its coefficients are from a field with positive characteristic

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, power-series

Let $k$ be algebraically closed field of characteristic $p>0$. Let's consider a power series $f(x,y)\in k[[x,y]]$. Under what conditions (on $n$, $f$, ...) there exists $g(x,y)\in k[[x,y]]$ such that $g(x,y)^n=f(x,y)$?

Comment: If $n$ is a power of $p$, then certainly. Otherwise, i'm not sure that there is a nice characterization

Comment: @Jake The coefficient should vanish outside $p$-power orders in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Jake has already hinted at the case where $n$ is a power of $p$, so it remains to consider the case where $p$ does not divide $n$. There you can apply *Hensel's Lemma* if the residue term of $f$ does not vanish.

> **Hensel's Lemma:** Let $R$ be a commutative ring, $I\lhd R$ an ideal such that $R$ is $I$-adically complete. Further, let $p\in R[X]$ be a polynomial and $\xi\in R$ such that $p(\xi)\in I$ and $p^{\prime}(\xi)\in (R/I)^{\times}$. Then there exists a unique $\chi\in R$ such that $[\chi]=[\xi]$ in $R/I$ and $p(\chi)=0$.

In your situation, pick $R=k[[x]]$, $I$ the maximal ideal, and $p=x^n - f$. Can you work out the details yourself?

As for the proof of Hensel's Lemma, you might want to try yourself - think of [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand symbol ⊲ in Hensel's Lemma (normal divisor?), what do $I$-adically and $(R/I)^x$ mean?

Comment: Oh, $I\lhd R$ just means that $I$ is an ideal in $R$, $I$-adically complete means that $R$ is complete in the $I$-adic topology - in your example, this means that infinite sums of power series of larger and larger degree have a well-defined meaning - and finally $(R/I)^{\times}$ means the unit-group of $R/I$.